# Shrink div's then restore them on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, user-interface

Ideally I want a windows 7 style minimize the div then restore. I want a method that  literally takes the div, shrinks and move it to the bottom left of the screen, then can be clicked on to restore it to the center. Please help! Here is my jsfiddle for the basic operation of moving the divs using buttons:

http://jsfiddle.net/UqWC6/1/

```
var clicked = 0; 
var restored = 0;
$("#go").click(function () {
if ($(".box" + clicked)) {
    $(".box" + clicked).animate({
        top: 400,
        width: "20px;",
        height: "20px;",
        opacity: 0.4,
    });
    clicked++;
} else {
    clicked = 0;
}

});
$('#go2').click(function () {
if ($(".box" + restored)) {
    $(".box" + restored).animate({
        top: -20,
        width: "140px;",
        height: "140px;",
        opacity: 1,
    });
    restored++;
} else {
    restored = 0;
}

});
```

Comment: Ok then how can i do this with UI

Comment: I just need something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/jasonday/ZSk6L/ that can work with mutiple divs in a row to scale.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/UqWC6/2/

I removed the incorrect semicolons. *And linked to jqueryUI in the fiddle.*

So changed these lines from

```
    width: "20px;",
    height: "20px;",


    width: "140px;",
    height: "140px;",
```

To this

```
    width: "20px",
    height: "20px",


    width: "140px",
    height: "140px",
```

Seems to work great now. Let me know if that's what you want.

---

EDIT: http://jsfiddle.net/UqWC6/3/ I fixed it so the third one only needs one click, instead of two.

I changed your html from this

```
<p>
    <button id="go">Save »</button>
    <button id="go2">Restore Next</button>
</p>
<div class="box0">box 1</div>
<div class="box1">box 2</div>
<div class="box3">box 2</div>
```

To this

```
<p>
    <button id="go">Save »</button>
    <button id="go1">Restore Next</button>
</p>
<div class="box0">box 1</div>
<div class="box1">box 2</div>
<div class="box2">box 3</div>
```

And changed this script line from

```
$('#go2').click(function () {
```

To this

```
$('#go1').on('click', function () {
```

---

EDIT http://jsfiddle.net/UqWC6/4/ I made it so that you can continue to loop through the clicks once they hit 3 clicks (reset them to 0)

added

```
if (clicked === 3) {
   clicked = 0;
}

if (restored === 3) {
   restored = 0;
}
```

Comment: Hey that's great! Could you fix my buttons that 'save' and 'restore' so that they always work/ reset after they hit the end? Thank you!

Comment: Or maybe restore just restores all of them to the origin

Comment: Hey thanks, it's pretty much perfect. I'm just trying to figure out how to reset the counters on the buttons!                clicked = 0;
        restored = 0;  are not working.